# Convert 'QueryDocumentSnapshot' to Json

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm trying to use streambuilder to receive data and turn this data to json for my model but getting error below; So my question is how can i convert stream data from firebase to json

**Error**

```
type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'
```

**FromJson method of model**

```
factory Review.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) => Review(
     //Bunch of random fields here);
```

**StreamBuilder**

```
 StreamBuilder<Object>(
                              stream: widget.reviewStream,
                              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshots) {
                                if (snapshots.hasData) {
                                  var data = snapshots.data.docs;
                                  return ListView.builder(
                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                    itemCount: data.length,
                                    itemBuilder:
                                        (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                      return Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                            vertical: 12.0),
                                        child: Padding(
                                            padding:
                                                const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                            child: ReviewBox(
                                              review: Review.fromJson(
                                                  data[index]),
                                              user: widget.user,
                                            )),
                                      );
                                    },
                                  );
                                } else {
                                  return Text('No Data');
                                }
                              }),
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call [data()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/data.html) method on `data[index]` to get `Map<String, dynamic>`, because the `data[index]` is a [QueryDocumentSnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot-class.html).

```dart
Review.fromJson(data[index].data());
```